# URL Rewrite module for IIS7 Not Handling Rewrite Rule Correctly

Tags: iis, url, module, url-rewriting

I have the attached redirect and rewrite rules.  Essentially, www.foo.com/vehicles/vehicle-detail.aspx?stockno=123456 is rewritten to www.foo.com/123456.  This works as expected with the rules I have in place.  Now, if I attempt to browse to a page that does not exist (i.e. www.foo.com/test.aspx) the rewrite rule qualifies and IIS attempts to forward the request to www.foo.com/vehicles/vehicle-detail.aspx (without the querystring).  On the vehicle-detail.aspx page I have code to redirect to the homepage if there isnt a valid stockno in the querystring, so this is what is happening.  I am not sure how to correct the rule(s), so that the condition does not qualify as true.  I have attached rules and screenshots of Failed Request Tracing I enabled to watch the request/rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="Redirect StockNo" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^Vehicles/Vehicle-Detail\.aspx$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^stockno=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

```
<rule name="Rewrite StockNo" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="Vehicles/Vehicle-Detail.aspx?stockno={R:1}" />
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something more unique for the friendly pattern.  If you know that it's always going to be digits, you can have:

```
<match url="^([\d]+)/?$" />
```

This will only match to www.foo.com/{digits} with an optional trailing slash.

Another option is to make the url something like www.foo.com/s/{stockno}/.  With the /s/ you have something unique that you can confidently match.  S is just an example that is short for stockno, so you can use what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Your response led me to think about how to configure what I needed.  Thanks!!